# What is the Java keyword that indicates a reference variable does not access an instance?

Tags: java, variables, reference, instance

I have tried all sorts of keyword related but I keep getting it wrong.

Comment: Does not acces which instance? Access how?

Comment: Do you mean `static`? That means something belonging to a class, not a specific instance.

Comment: Do you mean `null`? If so, it isn't a keyword, [it's a literal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.7). If you told us *what* you keep getting wrong, we might get somewhere.

Comment: The answer is null, thank you for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only word in Java that precisely meets your vague description is `null`. If so, it isn't a keyword, [it's a literal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.7).

Comment: The answer is null, thank you for your reply